# To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server

Tags: php

Estoy intentando instalar un tema en WordPress pero al hacerlo me sale esto, y no se que hacer, si por favor de pueden ayudar, gracias. [image]

Comment: Are you saying you don't have FTP credentials? Do you have any way of writing files directly on the server e.g. shell access instead? If not you may need to talk to your host for help.

Comment: (And I'm afraid this is an English language site sorry. There is [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) if you'd prefer.)

Comment: The root cause of this though is that your file permissions are set up so that WordPress can't write to the themes folder. Which may have been deliberate - I don't know - but does e.g. mean you'll need to make theme upgrades yourself too, WordPress can't do this automatically. Perhaps you want to change the file permissions here instead. Again talk to your host I think. Do image uploads work? Can you add new plugins?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to skip this popup on the every action (like plugin or theme activation) you can go to wp-config.php file and paste the code

```
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
define("FTP_HOST", "<server>");//for eg.localhost
define("FTP_USER", "<wordpress admin username>");
define("FTP_PASS", "<wordpress admin password>");
```

It works for me please try.

Comment: If you do that though, unless you've got extra protection on wp-config you're effectively giving anyone who can get read access to your server write access too. So you might as well just set your file permissions to let WordPress write to wp-content instead.

Comment: when adding the code in wp-config.php I get this error,"Installation failed: Could not create directory. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/robocito/wp-content/upgrade" no se que hacer